# excel VBA Chart Formatting - need to change the width of a line

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am trying to write code that will format a chart (myChart). Series line 2 and 4 are the 2 that I need to format so their weight = 1. I have tried following with no luck.

```
myChart.fullseriescollection(2).format.line.weigth = 1
```

I am pretty new to VBA, and I have never tried to reference chart object before, so I am unfamiliar with the proper syntax.

Thanks! See my code below.

```
Sub myChart()

Dim myChart As Chart, cht As ChartObject
Dim rngChart As Range, destSht As String
Dim rngData As Range

destSht = ActiveSheet.Name
Set myChart = Charts.Add
Set myChart = myChart.Location(where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=destSht)

With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange
    Set rngData = Union(.Columns(2), .Columns(9), .Columns(10), .Columns(11), .Columns(12))
End With

With myChart
.SetSourceData Source:=rngData, PlotBy:=xlColumns
.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
.ChartStyle = 209

*****Below is the first series line that I want to format*****
With .FullSeriesCollection(2)
    .ChartType = xlLine
    .AxisGroup = 1
End With

With .FullSeriesCollection(3)
    .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    .AxisGroup = 2
End With

*****2nd line I want to format*****
With .FullSeriesCollection(4)
    .ChartType = xlLine
    .AxisGroup = 2
End With
End With

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Activate

Set cht = ActiveChart.Parent
Set rngChart = Range("A1100:K1115")

cht.Left = rngChart.Left
cht.Top = rngChart.Top
cht.Width = rngChart.Width
cht.Height = rngChart.Height

Range("A2").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you tried recording macro ?

Comment: So here is what I found out, and it kind of answers my question: Inside one of my nested `with` sections, I can add a `.select`, followed by an additionally nested with section, `with selection.format.line`. From there I can simply place the code `.weight = 1` and it works fine...so I am curious as to why i have to include this additional code, it seems inefficient to have that many nested with statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
With .FullSeriesCollection(2)
    .ChartType = xlLine
    .AxisGroup = 1
    .Format.Line.Weight = 5
End With
```

Worked fine for me in Office 2016.

I would have commented, but I do not have a high enough reputation yet

Comment: Yeah that worked...I think I was writing in `width =` instead of `weight`

Comment: I did the same thing when I first tried it... Glad I  could help!